# Visually Distinguishing between plots of exponential and polynomial curves

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function, curves

Consider a plotted curve $C$ on an unlabelled axes that are linearly scaled. $C$ corresponds to either the exponential curve $2^x -1$ or the square curve $x^2$. I wish to know if there is a tell-tale difference between the two, based on their shape purely.

To clarify, I am not talking about two curves plotted together and telling which is which, to accomplish that I can just see which one is asymptotically greater. Nor am I talking about a mathematical method to tell them apart. For example, I could measure the ratio of increase and expect it to stay constant for the exponential curve and decrease for the polynomial one. I don't want to do this.

In the same way that you can tell the difference between a linear curve and the curve $ x^2$ very easily visually, is there some telltale aspect of exponential curve that immediately distinguishes them to the eye? Note I used $2^x -1$ because I want it to pass through the origin to better resemble the polynomial curves.

I want strictly a visual,not magnitude related telltale difference between a polynomial's shape and an exponential one in the positive XY quadrant. Below are two images to clarify corresponding to a polynomial and an exponential. Again, comparative analysis is not desired; take each curve as if it were presented in isolation.

For further clarification, there must not exist a shifting, or modification using sub-quadratic polynomial terms that renders the visual difference null.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The tangent at $(0,0)$ is horizontal for the parabola but has positive slope for the exponential.

Comment: Good point, but by modifying the polynomial slightly to $(x+1)^2-1$, we shift the 0 tangence out of sight and out of mind. Is there any way that is immune to possible perturbations that I could apply?

Comment: Right, but the same doesn't apply to $x$ and $x^2$; zooming out sufficiently in the first quadrant is sufficient to let you see that one is flat and one is curved. I'm asking if there exists any striking differences in the curvature of $x^2$ and $2^x$. You seem to believe there isn't, in the way that there is between the quad and the linear. The intuition behind my question is that polynomials and exponential are very different classes of functions, so how come there isn't any (or I'm not aware of any) striking characteristic differences in the curvature itself

Comment: You are not allowing any measurement whatsoever and now you even took away the one thing that can be seen without measuring anything, so I'd say there's no way to distinguish those curves under the conditions you are imposing.

Comment: There are striking differences in the curvatures of the graphs of $x^2$ and $2^x$, if you graph them over a large enough region. The exponential will always end up growing much faster, but you won't see that if you limit yourself to a small region around the origin. That goes for any pair of curves: $x^2$ and $1 - \cos(x)$ are very different curves, but you won't be able to tell the difference on a small region around $(0,0)$ if no measurements are allowed.

Comment: I see. Bizarre, even though they are wildly different functions

Comment: Does the drawing of tangents to curves count as "visual", or is it "magnitude related"? If it is allowed, then one could perhaps examine whether the length of the subtangent $y/(dy/dx),$ which is strictly increasing in both cases (regardless of which point of either curve is taken as the origin), appears to approach a fixed value (exponential curve), or appears to increase without limit ($n$th power curve).

Answer (score 1):

if you look closely around zero you can see that one of the curves is initially horizontal, whereas the other has a nonzero slope.

Slope is related to differentiation:

- the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$, which at $x=0$ is zero
- the derivative of $2^x - 1 = e^{x \log(2)} - 1$ is $\log(2) e^{x \log(2)}$, which as $x=0$ is simply $\log(2)$.

Hence in this case the curve that is horizontal at $x=0$ is the quadratic polynomial, whereas the exponential starts with a slope.

Note that if the polynomial were offset, for example considering $(x+1)^2 - 1$, this visual clue would fail.

Comment: Precisely! Is there a way to find a visual difference that is immune to perturbations of constants and lower order terms?

Comment: Not that I know of. If you allow polynomials of higher order, it gets harder and harder, as most functions can be well approximated by polynomials (for example using [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) or [Taylor Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series))